# HTML5 dragging element left does not show horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, overflow, scrollbars

I have a div that holds multiple draggable elements.
When I drag an elements to the right, the horizontal scroll bar appears and I can scroll the div. This is what it looks like:
[image: Example showing overflow to the right with scrollbar]

However, when I drag the elements left, the horizontal scroll bar doesn't show. Example:
[image: Example showing overflow to the left without scrollbar]

I have the overflow property set to auto.

I understand that this is the deafult behavior of the browser, and that not showing the scroll bar is "correct", however if anyone has any suggestions how to make the overflow also work when moving elements left, it would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 0):

No. When you drag an element to the right you are increasing the page width and triggering a horizontal scrollbar. When you drag an element to the left, you are simply moving it off the page.

You might try dynamically increasing the page width based on how far the element has been dragged outside the left edge of the page.

The browser is working as designed.